# Is it okay to blacklist one of the files in the node modules during npm run build: prod?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules

One of the files in my node modules is causing a issue, specifically showing this error: 'Module parse failed: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.' Is it okay to exclude this file during build? Any drawbacks? Should we exlude all node modules during build? Please someone explain this to me. If I exlude this file, I can able to build the application successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If a you or a module/package that you import/require relies on the module that errors you can't just exclude it from the build. If this is not the case you should be able to fix the error by deleting your node_modules folder and package.lock file and running `npm i`.

If the actual error persists, you need to modify your webpack config to include a loader for that file type. If you are using *create-react-app* you will have to `npm run-script eject` to do this. You should Google the loader you need for the filetype you have.